# How to upload large image datasets from kaggle to google colab?

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I wanted to work on a image dataset. I dont have local GPU, so i wanted to make use of free GPU on Google colab. But i don't know how to upload a large image dataset to colab.

Comment: Upload the dataset to drive and then transfer to colab. Or directly download the dataset on the colab.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Kaggle command-line client directly to download data sets in Colab.

Here's a step-by-step walk-through:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650918/8841057