# Download from a link that requires to log in

Tags: python, http, authentication

UPDATE: It looks like the link requires a log in, I updated the title.

This is a link for a particular Kaggle data file that I'm trying to download into Python (Google Colab if it makes a difference)

This is the link

https://www.kaggle.com/azathoth42/myanimelist/downloads/UserAnimeList.csv/9

Which I got from here

https://www.kaggle.com/azathoth42/myanimelist#UserAnimeList.csv

I tried using wget with the following code

```
!pip install wget
!wget -i https://www.kaggle.com/azathoth42/myanimelist/downloads/UserAnimeList.csv/9
```

Which didn't seem to work

I then tried

```
from urllib import request
request.urlretrieve('https://www.kaggle.com/azathoth42/myanimelist/downloads/UserAnimeList.csv/9' , 'download.zip')
```

The issue I now know is that it requires a log in.

Edit:

This link shows how to download Kaggle data into colab complete with an example notebook

[Using kaggle datasets into Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310470/using-kaggle-datasets-into-google-colab/50650918#50650918)

Comment: When I click on that link, I get redirected to a login page.  It seems your HTTP request will need to include login information.

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310470/using-kaggle-datasets-into-google-colab/50650918#50650918