# Loading Amazon fine food reviews dataset from kaggle into colab notebook

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm trying to import Amazon fine food reviews dataset into colab notebook, but it is not getting loaded when I list the datasets, how to get this dataset? Any help would be appreciated.

I followed this link [Using kaggle datasets into Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310470/using-kaggle-datasets-into-google-colab)

and it did not show all datasets, and i tried to search using kaggle dataset -s, It did not show anything.

Comment: Please share a notebook that shows what you tried and the error that you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Reading our CSV File
df=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/..."Your Path"../Reviews.csv")
df.head()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explicitly ask your question in text form in addition to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
!kaggle datasets download -d snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews
```